# How do you fix "Build failed: Android SDK dir was not specified, exiting."

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kivy, buildozer

I am trying to build a kivy apk and I keep getting this error, " Build failed: Android SDK dir was not specified, exiting.". What do I need to do to fix it?

and when i run:

```
 python3 -m pythonforandroid.toolchain create --dist_name=simpleapp --bootstrap=sdl2 --requirements=python3,kivy,android --arch armeabi-v7a --copy-libs --color=always --storage-dir="/home/haryo/kivy-game-2.0/.buildozer/android/platform/build" --ndk-api=21
```

i get:

```
[INFO]:    Will compile for the following archs: armeabi-v7a
[ERROR]:   Build failed: Android SDK dir was not specified, exiting.
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to...specify the sdk dir. Use the `--sdk-dir=...` argument to pass the path to the Android SDK.

You'll also need to do the same for the NDK.

Comment: So where do I add that. Is it in the python for android command?

Comment: Yes, see [the documentation](https://python-for-android.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart/).